# Python CGI script not working as hoped?

Tags: apache, cgi

I'm trying to run a motor through the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi using wiringPi, Apache and CGI python scripts. This is my CGI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wiringpi2
wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupSys()

wiringpi2.pinMode(11,1)
wiringpi2.pinMode(13,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(11,1)
wiringpi2.digitalWrite(13,0)

print "Status: 204 No Content"
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
```

I have exported the pins 11 and 13 and the above code runs the motor perfectly through the terminal without "sudo" but the motor doesn't rotate when I run this as CGI through the server (both in localhost and through another browser on LAN). I don't even run across any errors. There's nothing in the Apache error log as well.

I have tried to change the headers to print html and all that works fine, but the motor doesn't seem to budge.

Comment: Also, I have noticed that my /var/log/apache2/error.log is kind of broken. It doesn't show any errors since 1 week when opened in Leafpad GUI but I can see the new errors in the nano editor in the terminal. Still no errors related to my code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the file executable using chmod did the job. But I'm still not sure how I got the html output from the program if it wasn't executable.